# Window Service to listen service bus subscription

Tags: c#, windows-services, azureservicebus, .net-framework-version

I am planning to create a Window service that listen to a service bus subscription. I am not using top shelf. I use the native way to create the window service. My target framework is .Net Framework 4.6.2.
In the OnStart, I setup the listener to listen to a service bus but every time there is a new message on my subscription the MessageHandler method didn't get call .

```
protected override async void OnStart(string[] args)
{

    _logger.Information("App is running");

   client = new ServiceBusClient(connectionString, new ServiceBusClientOptions()
   {
       TransportType = ServiceBusTransportType.AmqpWebSockets
   });

    // create a processor that we can use to process the messages
    processor = client.CreateProcessor(topicName, subscriptionName, new ServiceBusProcessorOptions());

    try
    {
        // add handler to process messages
        processor.ProcessMessageAsync += MessageHandler;

        // add handler to process any errors
        processor.ProcessErrorAsync += ErrorHandler;

        // start processing 
        await processor.StartProcessingAsync();

        _logger.Information("Wait for a minute and then press any key to end the processing");

    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        _logger.Error(ex, "Error running");
    }
    finally
    {
        // Calling DisposeAsync on client types is required to ensure that network
        // resources and other unmanaged objects are properly cleaned up.
        await processor.DisposeAsync();
        await client.DisposeAsync();
    }
}

static async Task MessageHandler(ProcessMessageEventArgs args)  
{
       try
       {              
           var sqliteUploadFileDto = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<TestDto>(args.Message.Body.ToString());

       _logger.Information($"Received new message - {args.Message.Body.ToString()}");

       
       await args.CompleteMessageAsync(args.Message);
   }
   catch (Exception ex)
   {

       _logger.Error(ex, "Message handler error");
       throw ex;
   }
}

 static Task ErrorHandler(ProcessErrorEventArgs args)
 {
     _logger.Error(args.Exception, "Message handler error");
     return Task.CompletedTask;
 }

 protected override async void OnStop()
 {
     // stop processing 
     _logger.Information("\nStopping the receiver...");
     await processor.StopProcessingAsync();
     _logger.Information("Stopped receiving messages");
 }
```

Comment: I doubt that is a problem with the service. Could be a connection problem. Are you 100% the topic & subscription name is correct? Can you reproduce the problem with a demo console app?

Comment: yes, Subscription and topic name is correct. In a console app it is working fine

Comment: And `OnStart()` is being executed as expected? Could you show us the full console output of your service? How are you sending messages? The problem doesn't seem to be in the parts of the code you are showing us, so you need to provide more details.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The line `await processor.StartProcessingAsync();` starts the processing and then returns immediately. So the code then executes `await processor.DisposeAsync();`. You need to postpone the call to `Dispose` until `OnStop` is being called. In the current situation the process is not given enough time to process any incoming message.